# Is there function in PySpark that is equivalent to Pandas aggregate function any()?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pyspark

I'd like to translate the following pandas code to PySpark code

```py
pd_df.groupby(['colA']).agg(newCol1 = ('colB', 'count'),
                            newCol2 = ('colC', 'mean'))
                            newCol3 = ('colD', 'any')).reset_index()
```

The equivalent PySpark code would be

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
ps_df.groupBy(['colA']) \
    .agg(F.count("colB").alias('newCol1'),
         F.mean("colC").alias("newCol2"),
         F.any("colD").alias("newCol3"))
```

However, there is no aggregating function `any()` in `pyspark.sql.function`, (the other two works fine).

Any idea?

Comment: There is no built-in implementation for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in implementation for `any()`. Instead, I recommend using `first()`, as it might serve the same use and computationally it will not cause large re-shuffles. From the `pyspark` doc:

> Aggregate function: returns the first value in a group.
>
> The function by default returns the first values it sees. It will return the first non-null value it sees when ignoreNulls is set to true. If all values are null, then null is returned.
>
> Note The function is non-deterministic because its results depends on order of rows which may be non-deterministic after a shuffle.

If you wish to learn more see https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.first
I hope this helps!